# Launch ipython qtconsole on a specific environnement

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, anaconda

I try to launch iPython qtconsole on a specific env in Anaconda.
Suppose I have an env called "envir1", I use this command to activate then in the prompt `activate envir1`. 
Then I call `ipython qtconsole` but the env of the python is the root env and not "envir1".

Do you know a possible way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use this command:

```
$ source activate envir1
```

To exit this environment and return to the root one:

```
$ source deactivate
```

Comment: On my PC, even I activate an environnement by activate them, the ipython command use the root environnement. Any idea on that ?

Comment: you may have several versions installed and the `PYTHONPATH` may not be set properly. in the command line, `$ conda info`, `$ which ipython`, `$ conda list env`  will give you some clues.

Comment: It works. Tks !! It fact ipython is like to the environnement !